# How to display set of same string multiple in listView in different row?

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, android-arrayadapter

How to make my `ListView` displays the list of subject for the firstSemester multiple time in the `ListView` in different row
[image]

I want to make it looks like this
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, be more specific about your problem. What you have tried so far? When posting a code block don't post a print screen. Instead, copy and paste your code with the appropriate formatting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by adding it multiple times to your `ArrayList<> listItems` Or you can create two listItems and a custom adapter where you can add logic to repeat the one after another.

Comment: hai kush im new to android programming..if you can help me by writing the code it would be much better for me to properly understand. Thanks :)

Comment: do you need two columns? where in first column you add subject and in second you add detail, if you i would better recommend, to take lessons on listViews, and array adapters.

Comment: Hi kush i want it to looks like this

Comment: use two for loops

Comment: 'for(int i = 1; i <5; i++) for(int j = 0; j<semesterlength; j++) listitems.add(firstSemester[j])

Comment: This will add four set to your listitems